# What is the cheapest way to get from Tocumen airport to Albrook bus station?

Tags: budget, public-transport, airport-transfer, panama, pty

I'm landing in PTY airport at 17:00 and I want to catch the night bus to Almirante (Bocas del Toro) around 20:00. If there is a delay I know I'll need a taxi, but if not I think I have time to go to Albrook bus station on bus or similar. What's the cheapest way to get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bus Is Cheapest But You Need a METROBUS Card

The [English version of the Tocumen Airport webpage on public transport mentions only taxis](http://www.tocumenpanama.aero/index.php?cccpage=transporte_publico), which makes it easy to assume that taxis are the only form of public transport connecting the airport to the city. This is not the case however, as [the Spanish version of the Tocumen Airport webpage on public transport also mentions buses](http://www.tocumenpanama.aero/index.php?cccpage=transporte_publico&set_language=es). It also states that bus rides cost 0.25`PAB` at the time of writing, regardless of the journey distance.

Searching on the Panama public transport website yields the [Tocumen - Via Espana - Albrook bus line](http://www.mibus.com.pa/tocumen-via-espana-albrook/) which, as the name suggests, should take you yo Albrook. Note however that **you can't board a bus without swiping your METROBUS card first**. What [other websites](http://marvelustravel.com/transportation-shuttle-bus-taxi-minivans/panama-getting-around-rental-bus-transport-international-routes-shared-vans-collective.html) suggest is to ask for locals to swipe theirs for you in exchange for a bit more than the nominal bus fee.

### Taxis and Other Shuttle Services

You've probably also tried [Rome2Rio which also suggest a number of combinations with a taxi/driving segment](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Panama-City-Airport-PTY-Panama/Albrook). These include taxi-train combinations, which seem to be the cheapest (20-25`EUR`), as well as single taxi rides (30-35`EUR`). The last entry in Rome2Rio however mentions a shuttle, which seems to cost the same as a taxi ride (30-35`EUR`). Checking on [the shuttle service website](http://marvelustravel.com/transportation-shuttle-bus-taxi-minivans/panama-getting-around-rental-bus-transport-international-routes-shared-vans-collective.html) shows that these shuttles are not buses. Rather they are a private minibus/minivan service which might or might not take you to Almirante *per se* as this destination isn't shown on the aforementioned webpage.

Comment: The Spanish version of the Tocumen airport webpage mentions buses (http://www.tocumenpanama.aero/index.php?cccpage=transporte_publico&set_language=es). I've read that you can take a bus outside the airport, but it takes you to the city center, not explains the best way to go to other places.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I dug a bit more and found a bus route that takes you to Albrook from Tocumen. Couldn't find timetables though.